# Fantasy book series with wizard who grew up on the streets

Tags: story-identification, novel

This was a fantasy book series (5-7 books?) where the protagonist is a wizard who grew up on the street ..he is more willing to kill etc..he builds a castle for himself and the local king gets worried and plots to do away with him.

There's a scene where the king gives the wizard a deed to the land he has built the castle on and the wizard uses it as toilet paper.

There's also magic using gemstones, some kind of slaver's ring where he is forced to fight.

Eventually there's a big battle and I think he dies at the end.

Comment: There's good detail here, but the main thing missing from the [story id checklist](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info) is *when* did you read this? (and when do you think it might have been written)

Answer (score 7):

Could this be [*The Sorcerer's Path* series](https://www.goodreads.com/series/84484-the-sorcerer-s-path) by Brock E. Deskins? There are eight books, published 2011 to 2013 (plus two in a follow-up series).

The protagonist, Azerick, is forced to live on the streets after his family is killed at the start of the [first book](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/12796986-the-sorcerer-s-ascension), gets captured by slavers in the second book, builds a castle in the third book, and gets thrown into a demonic abyss at the end of the eighth book.

> Torn from a life of comfort and luxury, his family destroyed by
> political intrigues and aspirations, a young boy must quickly grow
> into a man before the deadly streets of Southport devour him. Follow
> Azerick through a page-turning adventure that pits him against
> thieves, thugs, murderers, and men of power that will stop at nothing
> to achieve their goals.
>
> Azerick must fight just to survive, but for him survival is not
> enough. A hunger to avenge the wrongs committed against him burns deep
> within. But that is not all that lies within the young man. Their is a
> power waiting to be unleashed that may be the key to achieving the
> justice and security he seeks--if it does not destroy him first.
>
> [image]

Comment: A good find and solid match to the description. I've taken the liberty of adding a book blurb and a cover image to help their recollection.